# Brackets sketch.js errors: Expected an identifier and instead saw 'let' and Stopping, (19% scanned) and ERROR:Parsing Error: Unexpected Token i

Tags: brackets-shell, sketch.js

[Brackets coding problem at sketch.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksBxO.png)

For the errors to be solved and have a perfect code for this.

Brackets sketch.js errors: Expected an identifier and instead saw 'let'

Stopping, (19% scanned)

ERROR:Parsing Error: Unexpected Token i